# How can I close a SpringBoot WebSocket server?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I imagine it's incredibly simple but I've been unsuccessful in my googling of how-to's, reading of documentation, and perusing of Spring classes.

[Spring's doc on their websocket api](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/websocket.html) has been useful and I can see that the project I'm familiarizing myself with uses what it describes to start a server:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketConfigurer {

     @Autowired
     private MyWebSocketHandler webSocketHandler;

     @Override
     public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
          registry.addHandler(webSocketHandler, "/");
     }
}
```

So it's easy enough to start, but I have no idea how to make it stop or pause. I'd like to add a feature to the application that takes down the server (and re-establishes it later) with a click of a button. But I have no ideas about how to stop or pause the server and the documentation doesn't seem to offer anything.

Answer (score 0):

the initialization/management/shutdown of websocket/http connections are handled by spring and tomcat (default). I don't think it's a good idea to deal with it on your own.

a solution would be to decouple (with two springboot apps) the websocket  service (which can be started/stopped manually) from the one (which is always up and running) with the "click of a button" page.